# Anouncements in Community Chatter Napili template

Tags: community, chatter, napili

I am trying to get Anouncements option similar to internal org chatter for Chatter groups in Community.

Internal org - 
[image]

On my Napili template Chatter feed - 
[image]

I tried changing global publisher layouts but it does not help. How can I add announcements etc on my Napili template Community chatter post?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not available for Napili template and currently there is an idea on the Ideaexchange .

Please upvote the below idea

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dn1qAAC

This requires custom lightning component build

Comment: Do you think this will add this feature?. Apparently need to add this by requesting Salesforce - https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_chatter_group_send_announcement_emails.htm

Comment: This might be good question on success community group community templates to find if this is in product road map